# Can I replace all asp controls with simple html controls form with same functionalities?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, xml, handler, transformation

I am having a project with **asp.net controls in the .aspx page and Javascript for validation and stored procedures for databases and asp:gridview** and datasource controls to display and do all such things. Now, I want to change the old aspx controls :

> asp:textbox, asp:dropdownlist

with `input, select` in html.

How much time will it take to develop 100 aspx forms in **simple html with query, xml datasource, CS file and generic handlers ??**

Have any one done this before or tried this one ? Will it be a good idea or a bad idea... All suggestions are welcomed :)

Added after MVC suggestions(to make it more clear)
I am typically want to complete that within a month. I use jquery and CS page to do all connections, create dynamic html and those things, handler to call those two files and aspx for design and database configuration file (config file with connections, security and those things )...

*My main doubt will I am able to obtain  perfect functionality ?*

Comment: the first question that comes to mind is "why?"

Comment: @shiznit123 : Better speed, better user interface, my old one was lacking  a lot in alignment, I want to use XML and jquery advantages in my project, and so on

Comment: Sounds like you might want to switch to MVC if you're going to through this whole exercise and don't want server controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a broad question, but I'll give it a shot.

1. Changing from asp:TextBox to input type="text" loses server side functionality.  So your aspx can't access the plain html control.  You could add an id and runat="server" to it, that would get you access to it again from the server.  But at that point, there's almost no reason to switch from asp:TextBox.
2. I'm not sure what you mean by generic handlers, but converting 100 forms depends on how much you want to change.  It could take a few weeks or half a year.
3. I may be wrong but it seems to me what you want is ASP.NET MVC.  It loses the whole form / viewstate paradigm and works in a simpler more standard HTML/javascript <-> ASP pure view <-> C# Controller way.  If you know HTML, javascript, and css, and are familiar with MVC, you will like this and be able to achieve anything you would with forms.  But, you know, cleaner.

Comment: You dont know what I mean generic handler, it is one of the many file types that popup when you want to add a new item in your Visual studio asp.net page. and I am not talking abt mvc :(

Comment: Oh I see, an ASHX page.  Yeah, then if you go that route, you'd be creating an MVC framework without using ASP.NET MVC.  That's why I suggested going with ASP.NET MVC.  It's easy to get started because you can just import your existing site and run it as is inside an MVC site.  Then you can migrate things slowly to the MVC pattern, something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/webformmvcharmony.aspx